# Using for-each-group with group-adjacent for grouping and wrapping in XSLT 2

Tags: xml, xslt, grouping, word-wrap

Obviously my understandig of how grouping in XSLT 2 works is not good enough. I´m sure that the approach with `xsl:for-each-group` with `group-adjacent` as attribute is right. However, I dont get the wanted result.

I want to group several adjacent elements in my XML source. The elements are identified through attribute values of a descendant element. I need to wrap them with a new element (e.g. `p div="lernz"`). Sometimes these elements appear as neighbours, sometimes not.

I did not get the right result with my stylesheet. Sometimes the element before the first item of what I think should be a group is matched. But in my results so far every single item of what I think is a group is wrapped. Where is the mistake? Any help is greatly appreciated.

XML Input

```
 <wx:sect>
  <w:p>
    <w:pPr w:val = 'Lern'/>
  </w:p>
  <w:p>
    <w:pPr w:val = 'Lern'/>
  </w:p>
  <w:p>
    <w:pPr w:val = 'Merk'/>
  </w:p>
  <w:p>
    <w:pPr w:val = 'Lern'/>
  </w:p>
  <w:p>
    <w:pPr w:val = 'Merk'/>
  </w:p>
</w:sect>
```

Desired Output

```
<wx:sect>
   <p div="wrapper-lernz">
       <w:p>
          <w:pPr w:val = 'Lern'/>
        </w:p>
        <w:p>
          <w:pPr w:val = 'Lern'/>
        </w:p>
    </p>
        <w:p>
          <w:pPr w:val = 'Merk'/>
        </w:p>
    <p div="wrapper-lernz">
      <w:p>
        <w:pPr w:val = 'Lern'/>
      </w:p>
    </p>
      <w:p>
        <w:pPr w:val = 'Merk'/>
      </w:p>
</w:sect>
```

My Stylesheet (part of it)

```
<xsl:template match="//w:p[w:pPr[@w:val]]">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="current()" group-adjacent="//@w:val = 'Lern">
         <p div="wrapper-lernz">
             <xsl:value-of select="current-group()"/>
          </p>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your template matches `w:p`, but if you want to group adjacent elements, you should be matching the parent `w:sect` tag. By doing `xsl:for-each-group select="current()"` you are trying to group a single element.

To handle only putting the "lern" elements in a container tag, you should group-adjacent= on the the "w:val" value, and then have an `xsl:choose` to decide whether to add a parent tag.

Try this template:

```
<xsl:template match="//w:sect[w:p[w:pPr/@w:val]]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="w:p" group-adjacent="w:pPr/@w:val">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key() = 'Lern'">
          <p div="wrapper-lernz">
             <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
          </p>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

(Note it also does `xsl:copy-of` instead of `xsl:value-of` as `xsl:value-of` just returns the text value of a node, not the node itself)

Comment: Ok, thanks. A quick test didnt get me the right result. To test your template correctly I need to restructure my own template - which will take some time. I will post my feedback as soon as I done with that.

Comment: Answer is correct, your template works for given xml source. For my 'real' source your template means to put a lot of transformations into one template - which is not nice and difficult to handle. I´ll work on this problem further.